# White flickering line - Laptop screen

Tags: laptop

The screen of my Samsung laptop is flickering and there is a horizontal white line showing at the top of the screen.

The following video will show the issue I am facing:

https://youtu.be/eJ35I-tE5uE

The things I have tried which didn't work:

Reinstalling the display driver

Tried removing and then reattaching the ram chips

Disconnecting the power cable from the monitor and reconnecting it

I have tried fiddling with the same wire assuming that maybe it is a case of a bad connection and the wire requires some slack

...

I haven't tried the following:

I haven't unplugged and replugged the power cable from the motherboard of the laptop though as I don't know how to open the bottom part of the laptop. It just didn't look that straightforward.

...

May I please know the best way forward to resolve this issue?

Many thanks.

MODEL: NP350V5C SAMSUNG LAPTOP

Comment: This looks like an electrical issue - the whole display shifts vertically when the line appears. Are you sure there is no damage to the display itself or the cables connecting it to the motherboard?

Comment: When you talk about the "Power cable to the monitor" what kind of cable are you talking about? A ribbon connection?

Comment: Attie, there is no damage to the display. However, I am not sure about the cables connecting to the motherboard. 

dmb: Yes, a ribbon connection. I opened the screen and disconnected and reconnected the ribbon connection. I also checked the wires, they seem to be okay.

Could it be the connection or the cable of the screen/monitor which connects to the motherboard on the top left side/near the charging port?

The left hinge of my laptop is not in great condition so I am assuming, perhaps it is that cable. I cannot unplug and replug that cable as it is hidden under the body of the laptop.

Comment: A reply will be much appreciated!

Comment: Since you've found an appropriate place for this question, could you delete the post on Meta Stack Exchange soon?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting another monitor to the PC to isolate the issue first?

My first instinct is that there is something inherently wrong with this monitor or the cords connected to it, as it is highly unlikely that something is wrong with the GPU/on-board graphics.

See if you can connect your laptop to an external monitor to test whether it'll work properly that way. Most modern laptops have an additional output port for monitors/TVs (e.g. HDMI).

Dropping (or sometimes slamming) a laptop can cause problems with the monitor's connection, which tends to be permanent or difficult to repair (and probably not worth it in that case).

Comment: Cake Princess, thank you for your reply. I have isolated the issue by connecting the laptop to the tv. There's no issue with the image on the tv so you are spot on. 

I think I need to re-connect the power cable of the laptop's monitor to the motherboard again to see if this resolves the issue.

Is there anything specific I need to keep in mind before opening up the laptop to 
 get to that cable?

Comment: By the way, in the meantime, if I choose to use the laptop by connecting it to the tv, can it further damage my monitor?

Comment: This is a video of the model of my Samsung laptop:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQI3MdFimsM

Comment: Please reply when it is convenient for you. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not an expert at repairing laptops, so I can't really help you on that front. You'll have to consult a repair store or try searching Google for your issue. Connecting your laptop to a TV or another display won't affect your laptop or monitor further.